# What's a program I can use to get realtime feed notifications (rss, atom, etc) on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu

I'd like to get notifications of any new posts I subscribe to with this program.

I'm on Gnome/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Google Reader](https://www.google.com/reader/)
- [Liferea](http://liferea.sourceforge.net/) for GNOME
- [Akregator](http://userbase.kde.org/Akregator) for KDE
- [newsbeuter](http://www.newsbeuter.org/) for terminal

Note that Atom/RSS feeds are not "realtime", they use periodic updates (every X minutes/hours).

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked [RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/). It can handle both RSS and Atom and is available for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla Thunderbird has worked for me.  It's not really "real time," but you can change how often updates are checked for.